# Does omniscience suggest a purely deterministic universe?

Tags: omniscience, problem-of-evil

My question is relating to one of the solutions to the problem of evil and free-will. Some philosophers state that to imagine someone as an observer who cannot affect anything but knows everything that will happen (omniscient), I.e. ‘James would pick ice-cream over broccoli’.

Given this idea, would it suggest we live in a purely deterministic universe without probabilistic outcomes?

From my idea, even if there was a powerless but omniscient being, it would suggest that the first-mover did cause everything, including all evil which does occur, so causes all evil. So therefore this solution to the problem of evil is false.

Assumptions: omniscience defined as all-knowing in this circumstance means they know everything that would happen; there is evil in the universe; this is not the most perfect universe possible; the first-mover is omnipotent.

Many thanks!

Comment: On what grounds do you assume that the only way to know what happens in the future is if the universe is deterministic?

Comment: There are also very good materials on the difference between determinism, predeterminism and fatalism.

Comment: "this is not the most perfect universe possible" - define perfect. There are lots of assumptions hidden in this little sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If you take omniscience to mean foreknowledge of absolutely everything that ever happens anywhere in the Universe, then by definition you are assuming that everything is knowable in advance, which is hard to reconcile with what appear to be unpredictable aspects of reality. You can dodge that difficulty by assuming that omniscience means a knowledge of everything it is possible to know, which means that god would not be able to foretell exactly what will happen. Given that interpretation, an omniscient god could have created the Universe with no idea that 13 or so billion years later, evil would evolve in a tiny part of it.

If you accept that, you might still ask why god tolerates evil. Again the use of the word 'possible' can come to the rescue of the person who wishes to argue in favour of the idea of god. If you take omnipotent to mean the ability to do absolute anything, then a benevolent god, having spotted that evil was afoot, might be expected to have done something about it. However, if you take omnipotent to mean the ability to do anything subject to the laws of physics, then you might suppose that god is some distance away from earth, and information about the evolution of evil here- which is a relatively recent development- would not have reached god yet, being unable to travel faster than the speed of light.

Given those definitions of omniscience and omnipotent, the idea of god can be consistent with the existence of evil, since god was unable to predict its development and has yet to learn of it.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your text, which is not always clear to me, as follows:

1. A creator created a world with an omniscient observer who cannot act
   as an agent. Then this world must be deterministic (My answer to your title question).
2. The created world contains some evil. The evil must be caused
   by the creator.
3. A created world with evil is not the most perfect possible world.
4. Hence the creator is not(!) omnipotent because he did not create the
   best world. (I assume you missed the word “not” in your text).

   The last conclusion is not correct, because the creator may be malevolent. But I assume that you don’t want to draw this
   conclusion. Hence I assume that you make the implicit assumption
   that the creator is benevolent.
5. The final question results: Can an omnipotent and benevolent creator
   create a deterministic world with an evil?

The final question reminds me to the scenario developed by Leibniz in his Theodicy. Leibniz’ conclusion: A better world without any evil is not possible. We do not know how, but the evil must have some positive effect, which outperforms the negative effect.

My conclusion: Leibniz invents an **ad-hoc argument**. He introduces a secrete cause to save the concept of an omnipotent, omniscient and benevolent creator. That’s not a valid argumentation.

The answer to the final question is “No”. Even lessening determinism and admitting some indeterminism in the world would not allow a positive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Define a **deterministic system** as one that has initial conditions, state transition rules, and a sequence of states that evolve over time depending only on the known initial conditions and the state transition rules.

Define an **all-knowing observer** as one that observes the initial conditions, knows the state-transition rules, and can predict the future estates of the system at any instant of time.

Given the existence of an all-knowing observer does this imply that the universe is deterministic?

I think it is a **tautology**. By definition the all-knowing observer is assumed to know the initial conditions and future states of the deterministic system.

Comment: Yes, but it's only a tautology because of the definition of the all-knowing observer you chose. Simply the definition "knows the future, period" does not allow the conclusion. There is a difference between being able to perfectly predict from transition rules, and simply already knowing the future state.

Comment: @kutschkem An all-knowing observer would, by implication, know the initial conditions and state transition rules of a deterministic universe! Otherwise the observer would not be all knowing! If the universe is not deterministic, then the all-knowing observer would not be able to know the future simply from the initial conditions and state-transition rules. The question, as posed, links deterministic universe with the existence of the all-knowing observer. So an all-knowing observer in a deterministic universe would by definition know it deterministically.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that an all-knowing observer does not imply a deterministic universe.

Answer (score -1):

A prime mover might have initiated a perfect universe knowing it would be perfect, but after a while something unforseeable went wrong, and this now powerless entity knows that many things have changed and unintended things will happen.

More generally, omniscience about the future requires predeterminism or fatalism, nit necessarily determinism (in particular not causal determinism).

All such discussions are not that useful philosophically without the reference to some religious belief system like the Christian faith. In secular philosophy, the definition of "evil" is much more nuanced to allow such simplistic questions as have been asked in the middle ages.

It also was easier to ponder this when believing in young earth creationism where Europe was the universe, it had been created a few hundred years ago, and the stars in the sky were just fancy nighttime decorations.

Those are questions relevant to a humanity with low education and high superstition.